# Debian fails to boot. Goes to intramfs shell. Matrix numbers on running of fsck

Tags: linux, debian, ext4, fsck

So in essence there appears to be a problem of some sort that is causing my laptop to be unable to boot.

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/T6f7K.jpg]
[image: https://i.imgur.com/sWpZuA5.jpg]

As can be seen there is an error in `/Dev/mapper/debian--vg-root` requiring a manual `fsck` check which then results in numbers cascading down the screen.

As I have a few months work of not backupped work on that laptop any help or guidance would be very much appreciated. If these numbers scrolling down the screen are in some way an indication of things being fixed then that's fantastic.

Comment: So what happens when you run `e2fsck`?

Comment: As Tero has suggested, run fsck from a recovery media

Comment: if you run a debian live usb if i remember correctly it has recover broken system, may be just for ubuntu it could help

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the linux distro.
I've had to do that to ubuntu a lot of times.

Answer (score -1):

I was in this exact same situation. Fortunately, Tero's advice helped me to escape The Matrix, in that running `fsck` from a recovery media allowed it to finish properly.